# Hightlighting selected text with rows in Java(Swing)

Tags: java, swing, highlight

How I can highlights([Highlighter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html)) in swing(JTextPane) not only text(with rows) when I select two and more rows. I need to highlight selection like in Intellij IDEA.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    JScrollPane textPaneWithScroll = new JScrollPane(textPane);
    this.getContentPane().add(textPaneWithScroll);
    this.setVisible(true);
});
```

[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/iztlbumz5/)

Comment: You must provide more details - is it about swing, html, etc.?

Comment: @home according to the tags, it is about swing

Comment: @msrd0: thanks, that tag has been added later. IMO details are still missing. Is it about tables, etc.? Some code might help as well.

Comment: @home Yes, that's true, the question still isn't usefull

Comment: @home: Sorry. I changed description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the highlight to extend to the right side of the text pane.

If so then you can use:

```
DefaultHighlighter highlighter =  (DefaultHighlighter)textPane.getHighlighter();
highlighter.setDrawsLayeredHighlights(false);
```

When you add the highlight to the text pane the offset must be one greater than the last character on the line so that the newline character is included in the highlight.